# É possivel aumentar a quantidade de carateres para justificar uma edição rejeitada?

Tags: novo-recurso, edições-sugeridas

Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar a quantidade de caracteres para justificar uma edição rejeitada.

No momento são aceitos 150 caracteres, lendo assim parece muito mas quando começa a escrever facilmente esse número é ultrapassado.

Eu queria poder rejeitar uma edição com uma mensagem menos robótica e se possível até instruir o autor que a fez, deixando claro o motivo de eu ter feito aquilo. Já rejeitei algumas edições de usuários novos e acho que isso é meio desanimador, ter uma rejeição por "não apresentar melhorias" e não explicar quais foram os erros e como ele poderia ter melhorado.

Comment: Não sei se você usou uma figura de linguagem para exagerar na quantidade de caracteres que um link possui ou você realmente copia o link da barra de endereços ao compartilhá-lo, de toda forma tenho que constatar que ao clicar no botão `compartilhar` que fica logo abaixo das tags o link de lá possui 45 caracteres, e se você retirar os números depois da última barra e a própria barra, cai para 39 caracteres. Não que sua solicitação não seja válida, só estou dando uma dica para você e qualquer outro membro em situação similar enquanto sua solicitação não é aprovada (não estou dizendo que será) :)

Comment: Ué, eu nem sabia que tinha como ver as edições rejeitadas?! Quer dizer, pelo jeito dá pra ver até o motivo da rejeição... mas nunca recebi uma not dizendo que "esta edição foi rejeitada"... só dos +2 quando é aceita... tem como ver todas as rejeitadas e seus fundamentos? @Math

Comment: @Math sim, mas a parte do link foi só um ponto que citei aqui. Na maioria das vezes uso a url menor (do botão compartilhar) mas não sei os outros usuários do site. Vai ver me negativaram pelo exagero dos "80"... kkk.

Comment: @gustavox sim, [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/45773).

Comment: humm, interessante, pelo link direto consegui ver, mas se entro por Análise, não tenho rep pra ver as edições sugeridas... e tbm não recebo notificação quando a edição é rejeitada... acho que seria legal se tivesse...

Comment: +1, não faz sentido um limite tão baixo.

Comment: @gustavox você pode ver seu histórico de sugestões de edição nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23400/gustavox?tab=activity Ao clicar por exemplo em "edição aprovada" você vai ver quem a aprovou. O mesmo para as rejeitadas.

Comment: @Math complementando, se for link dentro do próprio site pode ser relativizado, começando da barra. Teste esse: [/q/4473/#comment14175_4473](/q/4473/#comment14175_4473)

Comment: @Bacco interessante, não sabia. Valeu.